# ElectronJS Frontend can be modified after release?

Tags: electron

I am trying to learn Electon but, thre are a few questions that bothers me.

1. Can ElectonJS frontend be modified after publishig?
2. Can Devtools be opened to inspect the elements after publishing?

Comment: Yes for both questions.

Comment: @OJKwon thank you for the fast answer. How can I open devtools? and Is there any way to prevent them?